# HTML select options are inaccessible

Tags: html, select

I must have missed something very trivial, but I cant figure it out.
The select below shows 5 options (as expected), but I cant get access to option 6 and 7. The scrollbar is shown, but the browser doesnt allow me to move it down

```
       <select size='5' multiple name='driver[]'>
        <option value= >(No Driver Filter)</option>
        <option value=drivername=''></option>
        <option value=drivername='alex'>alex</option>
        <option value=drivername='marc'>marc</option>
        <option value=drivername='frank'>frank</option>
        <option value=drivername='james'>james</option>
    <option value=drivername='michael'>michael</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The problem is likely somewhere else in your code as it works fine for me as is. **http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBowdm

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue in Chrome 39, Mac. Your markup looks clean, though the blank option would probably be better markedup as an `<optgroup>` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup

Comment: When I try it on www.W3schools.com on Mac, it shows the effect I describe. Maybe only a problem for Safari?

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is not well formatted . You should use double quotes for attribute values.

```
  <select size="5" multiple="multiple" name="driver[]">
        <option value="" >(No Driver Filter)</option>
        <option value="drivername=''"></option>
        <option value="drivername='alex'">alex</option>
        <option value="drivername='marc'">marc</option>
        <option value="drivername='frank'">frank</option>
        <option value="drivername='james'">james</option>
    <option value="drivername='michael'">michael</option>
</select>
```

Comment: very starnge. It works with IE, but not with Safari on Mac. WEIRD!